# Trouble with TSQL calculation - date diff giving me troubles

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datediff, udf

I am having getting proper outputs for this functions. Does datediff only calculate the difference in days for days in the same month?
When I pass in a date in the form of '01 Jan 2015' it always sends me back a 0 =/ did I miss something in my logic or syntax?

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.CanPolicy
(
    @ReservationID int,
    @CancellationDate date
)
RETURNS smallmoney
AS
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @DepositPaid smallmoney
        SET @DepositPaid = (SELECT ResDepositPaid
                            FROM Reservation
                            WHERE ReservationID = @ReservationID)
        DECLARE @ResDate date
        SET @ResDate = (SELECT ResDate
                        FROM Reservation
                        WHERE ReservationID = @ReservationID)
        DECLARE @CanceledDaysAhead int
        SET @CanceledDaysAhead = DATEDIFF(day, @ResDate, @CancellationDate)
        DECLARE @result smallmoney
        SET @result = 0
        SET @result = CASE WHEN @CanceledDaysAhead > 30 THEN 0
                        WHEN @CanceledDaysAhead BETWEEN 14 AND 30 THEN @DepositPaid * 0.25 + 25
                        WHEN @CanceledDaysAhead BETWEEN 8 AND 13 THEN @DepositPaid * 0.50 + 25
                        ELSE @DepositPaid
                    END
        RETURN @result
    END

GO
```

Comment: You have said you get error when `@CancellationDate = 01 Jan 2015` , please specify the value of `ResDate` which is used in calculation..

Comment: Don't know all the parameters of the test scenario, but I think the datediff parameters need to be switched: `DATEDIFF(day, @CancellationDate,  @ResDate)`  Otherwise if cancellationdate is before reservationdate, datediff will always return a negative value, making the `case` results incorrect.

Comment: Also a sidenote, you can get depostipaid and resdate in one go: `SELECT @DepositPaid = ResDepositPaid, @ResDate = ResDate FROM Reservation WHERE ReservationID = @ReservationID`

Comment: @Me.Name What Jake has done is right as `Select` statement is a non-standard assignment statement. In case there are two `ResDate` for a given `ReservationID` then assignment via `Select` won't thorw any error and will simply assign any of the two qualified values. While Assignment via `Set` will raise error so that we can be sure out of two which `ResDate` should be selected.

Comment: @Me.Name, nice catch! The switching of the values in DATEDIFF did it. Looks like I need to double check my reading, reading the documentation for DATEDIFF was the first thing I did and I swear it subtracted the right value from the left, not left from right.

Comment: @Mini Not sure I agree with you there, multiple results for an id should not happen and can otherwise be simply resolved with a top 1, but the current setup causes 2 trips to the table instead of one. Won't matter much in the grand scheme of things perhaps, but was only notifying the OP of the possibility in case it was unknown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, DATEDIFF counts dates in between. Try:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(day,{ts'2105-01-01 00:00:00'},{ts'2105-04-01 00:00:00'})
```

Could be a date format issue...

Are you sure, that @ResDate is set correctly?

EDIT: New approach with CTE

```
DECLARE @ReservationID INT=123;
DECLARE @CancelationDate DATE=GETDATE();

WITH ReservationCTE AS
(
    SELECT ResDepositPaid 
          ,ResDate
    FROM Reservation
    WHERE ReservationID=@ReservationID --assuming that ReservationID is a unique key!
)
,ReservationCTEWithDateDiff AS
(
    SELECT ReservationCTE.*
          --EDIT: switched dates due to a comment by Me.Name
          ,DATEDIFF(DAY,@CancelationDate,ResDate) AS CanceledDaysAhead
    FROM ReservationCTE
)
SELECT CASE WHEN CanceledDaysAhead>30 THEN 0
            WHEN CanceledDaysAhead BETWEEN 14 AND 30 THEN ResDepositPaid * 0.25 + 25
            WHEN CanceledDaysAhead BETWEEN 8 AND 13 THEN ResDepositPaid * 0.50 + 25
            ELSE ResDepositPaid END AS MyReturnValue
FROM ReservationCTEWithDateDiff
```

Comment: @ResDate takes a value from my select that is in my DB as a "date". Does date in general store dates in the same format if they are the same data type? Or if there are, for example two dates, could they somehow be stored differently and conflict when compared with a DATEDIFF? Edit: added commas to make my question more understandable. Edit: Will let you know if the {}'s work, trouble connecting to my remote db. Not ignoring your thought input =)

Comment: I gave you another approach which is much better in performance (especially if "Reservation" is filled with many rows... Give it a try.. and please vote up if helpfull thx

Comment: it won't let me upvote. I'm a newbie on here ugh but I will remember to comeback and upvote it once I get up to 15. If that is a thing of course! Thanks again for the thoughtful input!

Answer (score 1):

I think the correct and short version of your function is this - please give it a try:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.CanPolicy
(
    @ReservationID int,
    @CancellationDate date
)
RETURNS smallmoney
AS
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @DepositPaid smallmoney,
                @CanceledDaysAhead int

        SELECT  @DepositPaid = ResDepositPaid,
                @CanceledDaysAhead = DATEDIFF(DAY,ResDate,@CancellationDate)
        FROM    Reservation
        WHERE   ReservationID = @ReservationID


        RETURN CAST(CASE WHEN @CanceledDaysAhead > 30 THEN 0 ELSE
               CASE WHEN @CanceledDaysAhead BETWEEN 14 AND 30 THEN @DepositPaid * 0.25 + 25 ELSE
               CASE WHEN @CanceledDaysAhead BETWEEN 8 AND 13 THEN @DepositPaid * 0.50 + 25 ELSE
               @DepositPaid END END END AS smallmoney)

    END
GO
```

The main problem was your case-when block i think...

Comment: The issue ended up being DATEDIFF, though I am new to SQL. Is it best practice to put an "END" for EACH "WHEN"?

Comment: `CASE WHEN <expression> THEN <truepart> ELSE <falseparte> END`

Answer (score 0):

You may have resolved this now, however one way I have handled date differences with no care for the difference being a + or - value is to use ABS:

[ABS on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189800.aspx)

This way the case statement doesn't need to differentiate between them.